# How to specify on which screen of the android phone my app icon will be placed?

Tags: android

How to specify on which screen of the android phone my app icon will be placed when it installs?

For instance, place icon on 2nd screen. Currently it places app icons on the last screen.

Note:
It is surprising if one has no control over it. I have 5 screens on my T-Mobile S7. Even though I have empty spots on the prior screens, it insists on placing the new icon on the last screen. Perhaps this is an opportunity for a new android feature of an 'organizer' layout for the android screens.

Comment: Interesting question. is that even possible? i think it is placed wherever there is an empty spot.

Comment: @MehranB No, I have empty spots on the prior screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that is under the control of the launcher implementation (and, perhaps, the user). There are hundreds, if not thousands, of launchers, both pre-installed and user-installed.

Comment: It is surprising that one has no control over it. I have 5 screens on my T-Mobile S7. Even though I have empty spots on the prior screens, it insists on placing the new icon on the last screen. Perhaps this is an opportunity for a new android feature of an 'organizer' layout for the android screens.

Comment: @likejudo: "I have 5 screens on my T-Mobile S7" -- there is no requirement for a launcher to support multiple screens. "it insists on placing the new icon on the last screen" -- there is no requirement for a launcher to support icons. A launcher could be a scrolling plain text list.